# How to wait for guzzle request to be completed while doing something else during waiting?

Tags: promise, httprequest, guzzle

I want to do something in a loop while a guzzle request is going on and then just continue the script when the request ends, for example I want to do something like this :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$promise = $client->headAsync("https://www.google.com");
$promise->then(
  function (ResponseInterface $res) {
    echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
  },
  function (RequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }
);
while($promise->getState() === "pending"){
  $queue = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\queue();
  $queue->run();
  echo "Waiting\n";
  sleep(1);
}
```

and this code just prints "Waiting" for ever. how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for the same answer, so here is what I found, You need to `tick` the curl request (so that request(s) are actually processes).

Working example:

```php
$curl = new \GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler();
$handler = \GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack::create($curl);
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['handler' => $handler]);

$promise = $client->headAsync("https://www.google.com");
$promise->then(
  function (ResponseInterface $res) {
    echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
  },
  function (RequestException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
  }
);

$queue = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\queue();
while($promise->getState() === "pending"){
  $curl->tick();
  //echo "Waiting\n"; Commented out as it prints A LOT without sleep, but sleep slows down the rest.
}
```

I put this code together after looking at this issue: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1127